# Marriage on a student visa possible in Germany?

Tags: visas

I am an Indian national, my wife to be is a Turkish national but was born in Germany and has a permanent residence permit, she can apply for German citizenship anytime but doesn't see any benefit although she would consider it if it makes the marriage process easier. I am in Germany on a student visa, i have been here only 6 months now and managed to convince my spouse's parents to give their blessings for the marriage which took a lot of effort and patience but that's another story.

My question is can i get married in Germany while i am on a student visa and completing my masters degree. My gf is doing her bachelor's degree at the same university. Or do i have to wait till i finish my studies and then go back to India and apply for a marriage visa. What would be the best course of action, any ideas or suggestions would be very welcome. What about marriage in Denmark, will that be valid in Germany?

Comment: Not really a travel question. Questions about long term immigration, settlement, etc. belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: Turkey is not (yet) part of the EU. German nationals can travel visa-free to many places in the world. And EU freedom of movement principles apply to you if you are married to an EU citizen. if I were her I would get the German citizenship yesterday.

Comment: You will need certified translations of quite a lot of documents, so the best approach is to simply *ask* a lawyer who knows family and visa law. That will cost some money, but you get competent answers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, a very Travel-centric answer. Germany discourages dual citizenship and depending on her age group the OP's fiancee might have to renounce her Turkish citizenship to become German. Plenty of people would rather stay a permanent resident.

Comment: @o.m. This is a good point. It's still something I would consider and not just reject out of hand.

Comment: Reposted on Expatriates here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/marriage-on-a-student-visa-possible